# Does alpha radiation penetration depth decrease exponentionaly with distance?

Tags: radioactivity

imagine there is 1mm² square area with thin film of Americium 241,kind of like the button in smoke alarms,lets theoreticaly imagine it gives 1000 becquerel of 5 MeV alpha radiation,that is 1000 particles per second.Now I know Americium gives different energy alpha and other kinds of radiation and the becquerel rate would be higher but for the sake of simplicity lets imagine it like I described.

Now lets imagine square target with 1mm² size that is ahead of the Americium,there is air between them,if the target is away set distance,like 2cm or 4cm,on average how many alpha particles will hit it per second?

What I want to know is the graph showing how many particles hit the target with increasing distance,is it exponentional or is it more complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha particles interact with matter via multiple small interactions.
The word "small" is used to indicate that the energy lost by an alpha during each interaction is small compared with the kinetic energy of the alpha.
So the alpha progresses through matter slowly losing kinetic energy.

So the graph of count rate which is proportional to the flux rate of alpha particles against absorber thickness looks something like this.

[image].

So all the alphas travel roughly the same distance through matter.

Here is a graph of range of alpha particles in air against energy of alpha particles.

[image]

So you 5 MeV alphas will hardly be absorbed by 4 cm of air.

---

At the other extreme is the all or nothing interaction where one interaction stops the passage of a particle.
This would result in an exponential drop of the flux rate with thickness of material.

Comment: That is perfect post! Thank you very much Farcher!